# Receiving errors for a domain I don't control

Tags: asp.net, error, hacking

I have my site set up to email me whenever an error happens, and recently I've been getting an occasional notification (a few per day) about a page not found error, but the weird thing is that the error is for a domain other than my own. Here's an example of the error (my domain isn't `ncbels.org`). Any idea what could be causing this?

I suspect my site is being used to probe/attack other domains somehow (do you agree?). I'm not sure how to track it down without more information. I searched all my site files for references to that domain, as well as any free text fields in my database, and didn't find anything. My hosting provider ran a scan on my site and said it came up clean.

Error in page `https://mail.ncbels.org/owa/auth/logon.aspx?url=https://mail.ncbels.org/owa/&reason=0`

> Message The file '/owa/auth/logon.aspx' does not exist.
>
> Trace   CheckVirtualFileExists at offset 9984736 in file:line:column
>   :0:0    GetVPathBuildResultInternal at offset 475 in
>   file:line:column :0:0
>   GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert at offset 103 in file:line:column
>   :0:0    GetVirtualPathObjectFactory at offset 165 in
>   file:line:column :0:0
>   CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath at offset 43 in file:line:column
>   :0:0    GetHandlerHelper at offset 31 in
>   file:line:column :0:0    GetHandler at offset 37 in
>   file:line:column :0:0
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute at offset 346 in
>   file:line:column :0:0    ExecuteStep at offset 155
>   in file:line:column :0:0
>
> StackTrace at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp) at
>   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context,
>   String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) at
>   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context,
>   String requestType, String virtualPath, String path) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> Query String url=https%3a%2f%2fmail.ncbels.org%2fowa%2f&reason=0
>
> User Name
>
> Source System.Web
>
> Help
>
> Error Code
>   -2147467259
>
> Form Data

Comment: I'm going to guess that the system you have installed that emails you of errors is faulty. Each server that hosts websites will have a web server installed that produces results of each incoming requests in logs. If the web server is apache, then look in error_log and access_log files. Its very likely some remote user or robot is trying to access files that just simply are not supposed to exist.

Comment: Yeah, I get those errors as well: sometimes a robot scans my site looking for files it hopes exist so it can exploit a vulnerability, so I get a bunch of 404's for that. However, they're always for my own domain. This one is listing a domain I don't control in the error, which is what has me concerned. It makes me think that my site is being made to make a request to a remote server.